# I have problems booting windows 7 with logitech usb unifying receiver connected

Tags: windows-7, usb, logitech-mouse, logitech-unifying-receiver

For the last month I have been having problems booting windows 7 when my Logitech unifying receiver is connected. The computer comes on but doesn't even get to the BIOS splash screen and there is no POST beep. If I touch the power button the computer goes off instantly. 
If I remove the Logitech unifying receiver the PC will boot up without problem. 
I am using a Logitech Performance MX mouse. Previously I was using a M505 with the same unifying receiver.

PC spec 
Intel Core i5 2500K Sandy Bridge
ASUSTek V-P8H67E 
8GB RAM

Windows 7 64-bit  SP1 with auto updating on.